# Builded angular application doesn't apply global styles

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

As I said, my application doesn't use global styles from src/styles.css if I build it with "ng build --prod" command, but it works ok if I run it with "ng serve". There I declare a set of rules and import one css from angular material library. styles.css looks something like this:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

...

@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

...
```

Application scaffolded with angular-cli and I made no changes in .angular-cli.json. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you looking in the .angular-cli.json there's a property called styles and this is where you can import styles from other packages from npm. This might fix the issue you are having

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757730/4399281