# Why are my CSS files ignored with Angular CLI when in prod mode?

Tags: angular-cli

I have what I think is a standard .angular-cli.json file.  In apps[0] it has:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

The above works fine with an "ng build" or an "ng serve".  However, if I do an "ng build --prod" these two css files are ignored.  The way I am getting around this is by using a CDN version of bootstrap.min.css and adding styles.css to a publicly available resource (Azure blog storage) and then referencing them from index.html.

FWIW, if I do an "ng serve --prod" it still works in my localhost/dev environment.  But "ng build --prod" does not.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: if you do `ng build --pord` do you have styles bundle outputed in `dist` folder ?

Comment: Yes, I have a "styles.<stuff>.bundle.css" file and it appears to have what I want in it.

Comment: I wonder if you `npm install -g http-server` and then serve the `dist` folder with `http-server` what would be outcome of that?. Also can you see if css bundle gets loaded in network tab  in dev tools?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, did you win?

Answer (score 14):

you have this problem because of the order of css file when bundling them, the only possible solution now is to let only style.css file like this:

```
 "styles": [
   "styles.css"
  ],
```

and import bootstrap.min.css inside your style.css

```
@import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

that willmake your app work in local and prod, the alternative solution is build with --extract-css=false

```
ng build --prod --extract-css=false
```

Comment: Was having the same issue; the styles.css was getting created with my stuff inside and it was linked to the index.html but my global csses and material theme was not getting reflected or rendered to the page, only when I open devtool and from source tab I was adding even a single space to styles.css it was getting applied. I search for hours for this and there was only solution to extractCss to JS. which was a bit disturbing on prod level. This solution worked for me even without extractCss. I was on Angular 12.